# Why an Oracle OCCI program compiled in Win 7 x86 VC++10 crashes in a Win XP sp3 client PC?

Tags: visual-c++, oracle11g, occi

I generated a VC++ program under Win 7 32bits using Oracle  OCCI library. It works very well in my computer,  but when I copy the executable, the oraocci11.dll, and  oci.dll to a  client machine, which does not have VC++ but it has the VC10 distributable installed, it crashes. I am many hours trying to solve this without success.

Did anybody experienced this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason of the crash. In my case I must also include the next components:
oraociei11.dll
oraociei11.sym

I really should install all the instantclient components in the user computer but does noy justify because the standalone program I made only recovers little information.

Regards.